# Ensure I close the connection, but also just throw the exception

Tags: ruby

I want to ensure my @client is closed, but I also want the exception to be thrown like it normally would.

Is this the correct patter?

```
@client = ....

begin
   # code here
rescue
   # ????
ensure
   @client.close
end
```

Should I call raise in my rescue?

Comment: Unless you care about rescuing the error you can just use `begin` and `ensure` without `rescue` otherwise yes just re-raise the error after you have done what ever you need to in the `rescue` block (e.g. Logged the error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to "do anything" with the exception here, and just let it get `raise`d like normal, then simply:

```
@client = ....

begin
  # code here
ensure
  @client.close
end
```

Or, if you *do* want to do something with the exception, then:

```
@client = ....

begin
  # code here
rescue => e
  puts e.message # Or whatever...
  raise e        # Then re-raise it!
ensure
  @client.close
end
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that `ensure` can go at the method level so you don't necessarily need a `begin`/`end` framing block for it if you're not too concerned about precisely where the exception occurs. In that case, though, you'll want to do `@client and @client.close` or `@client&.close` to ensure you don't try and close a `nil` handle, something that'd happen if `@client = ...` throws.